# Appdelegate setup for SKPaymentTransactionObserver

Tags: ios, swift

I've setup a `PurchaseViewController` which has been working fine except for multiple app store sign-ins which I've realised is the `SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)`. I need to insert this into the `Appdelegate` class at`DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function. When I do this:

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
{        
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0/255.0, green: 115/255.0, blue: 158/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()]

    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}
```

I get `Type Appdelegate does not conform to protocol "SKPaymentTransactionObserver`.

Can someone please point me to where i'm going wrong?

Comment: Maybe a missing delegate method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have declared your `AppDelegate` to conform `SKPaymentTransactionObserver` but you have not implemented 
`paymentQueue(_:updatedTransactions:)` which is a **required** method. That's why Xcode is not happy.

In your `AppDelegate` implement it and the Xcode will stop complaining.

See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentTransactionObserver_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/SKPaymentTransactionObserver/paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:).

Comment: Yes, the paymentQueue(_:updatedTransactions:) method is already implementated in another viewController class. Would you suggest creating a singleton. Would that be the accepted procedure here?

Comment: If you are not implementing the delegate method here, please remove `SKPaymentTransactionObserver` from AppDelegate. Also it will be wise to Build some helper class to manage In app purchase and Delegates. Need not be singleton but wont harm either.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, managed to get it to work.....

created a singleton to access the PurchaseViewController...

```
import UIKit

**let PVC_Share = PurchaseViewController.PVC_share**


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
{

    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0/255.0, green: 115/255.0, blue: 158/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()]


   **PVC_Share.paymentObserver()**

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}
```

then created a function in my PurchaseViewController so when the app launches it fires the transactionObserver

PurchaseViewController:

```
func paymentObserver()
{   
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)

}
```

and now i'm not getting the annoying multiple pop-up for login.
thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4**

Just read and apply this solution from [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/setting_up_the_transaction_observer_for_the_payment_queue).

You need to have a class with SKPaymentTransactionObserver and updatedTransactions function.

**Class with SKPaymentTransactionObserver**

```
class StoreObserver: NSObject, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {
   static var shared = StoreObserver()

   override init() {
      super.init()
   }

   func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
      for transaction in transactions {
         if transaction.transactionState == .purchased {
            // Payment Success 
            SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
         } else if transaction.transactionState == .failed {
            // Payment Failed 
            if let error = transaction.error {
                let errorDescription = error.localizedDescription
                print("Transaction failed due to error: \(errorDescription)")
            }
            SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Now, on your AppDelegate you call your StoreClass and add and remove the observer.

**AppDelegate File**

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

   var window: UIWindow?
   let iapObserver = StoreObserver.shared

   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
       // Override point for customization after application launch.
       SKPaymentQueue.default().add(iapObserver)
       return true
   }

   func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
       // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
       SKPaymentQueue.default().remove(iapObserver)
   }
}
```

For make a request and test, just try this somewhere (like a Button action):

```
if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
   //Can make payments
   let paymentRequest = SKMutablePayment()
   paymentRequest.productIdentifier = productID
   SKPaymentQueue.default().add(paymentRequest)
} else {
   // User can't make payments.
}
```

Comment: I'm testing this when using offer codes, but updatedTransactions never gest triggered. Any suggestions?